# Objective C Singleton with class hierarchies

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, singleton, hierarchy

I have a class Parent and a class Child. Child derives from Parent. I only instantiate the Child class, the parent gets never initialized directly, only by the child.
I need at least Parent to be a singleton. If that does not work, Child being a singleton is okay too.
I tried the following but that didn't change it to a singleton:

```
static MySingleton *sharedSingleton;

+ (void)initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }
}
```

The Child class calls [super init] to instantiate the Parent. Can you help me here?

EDIT: I add some background information for my solution (architecture): I have a web service client which has a connection to a web service. I have a base class (Parent) which has information about the connection (authenticated, how to connect etc) and I have different child classes which derive from this base class. The need for different child classes is that one child is responsible for a set of web service logic and another child is responsible for another set of web service logic. The problem is, I want the connection information to be singleton (because they all use only ONE connection, not many).

Comment: That `initialized` variable is superfluous, why not check for `if (sharedSingleton == nil)`?

Comment: Maybe you could briefly explain what you are trying to achieve, as having Parent be a singleton and a Child deriving from it not looks a bit messy to me. Maybe there is a better solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you are asking doesn't make sense, you seem to be confusing *relationship* with *inheritance*. If you have:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject ...
@interface Child : Parent
```

Then *every* `Child` you create *is a* `Parent` as well, indivisibly part of itself, there is no way to split the `Parent` from the `Child` - you have a single object. Using inheritance does not give you multiple children with a single shared parent.

If you want many children to share a single parent then you need your `Child` class to *have a* `Parent`. For example:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject ...

@interface Child : NSObject

@property (readonly) Parent *myParent;

- (id) initAsChildOf:(Parent *)parent;

...

@end
```

used as:

```
Parent *theParent = [Parent new];
Child *firstChild = [[Child alloc] initAsChildOf:theParent];
Child *secondChild = [[Child alloc] initAsChildOf:theParent];
```

If you wish you can make `Parent` a singleton class (only one instance possible), or a shared instance class (one shared instance, other instances possible).

With inheritance, as opposed to a relationship, it is hard (but not impossible ;-)) to derive from a true singleton class and if you do so the derived class is itself a singleton.

You can derive from a *shared instance* class; and you could write the class (hard again) so that you can have one and only one instance which is not indivisibly part of a instance of a derived class.

Note: the other answers so far have all provided you with code to produce a *shared instance* class, a *true singleton class* is a little more involved (you can find the code in Apple's documentation) and often a shared instance class is sufficient.

HTH and I've haven't misunderstood your question completely!

Comment: thx, can you add explanation about the difference between a true singleton and a shared instance? I can't find anything useful in apple's documentation (sometimes the docs are too old). I added some background information to my question. What would you recommend to that?

Comment: A _true singleton_ is a class which can have at most one instance; in Objective-C to create one typically involves overriding `allocWithZone` and/or `init` to ensure that any attempt to create an instance returns the _same_ unique instance. A _shared instance_ class is simply a class with a well-known instance which is easy to obtain, typically using a class method such as `sharedInstance`; other instances of the class may exist. Many Cocoa classes follow the later model, e.g. `NSFileManager` with its `defaultManager`.

Comment: I acutally found out, that if I use the singleton code with the dispatch_once_t logic I can't use allocWithZone. Just for information. so how can I prevent someone using alloc on my singleton then?

Comment: If you look at [this singleton](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/SingletonDesignPattern) code, which is based on [Apple's](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31) you will see it uses an `@synchronised` construct; if you wished you could replace that code with a version which uses `dispatch_once`.

Answer (score 1):

A more thread safe option would be something like:

```
+(MySingleton *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MySingleton *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line static BOOL initialized = NO; below this line static MySingleton *sharedSingleton; like this

```
static MySingleton *sharedSingleton;
static BOOL initialized = NO;
+ (void)initialize
{
  if(!initialized)
  {
     initialized = YES;
     sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
  }
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern for this is:

```
static MySuperclass *singleton = nil;
+ (void)initialize {
    if (self == [MySuperclass class]) {
        singleton = [[MySubclassProbabl alloc] init];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different from the other answers, this is the modern way to create a singleton

```
static MySingleton * volatile sharedInstance = nil;

+(MySingleton*) sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Also, by the wording of your questions and intended use of singletons (with parent/child relationship), I'd say that you have to rethink your architecture.